# associate a number to each link html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put a number to each link selected from the DOM, using js.
For that, i have made a function using a map method in order to associate all the links with a key

```js
function mapLinks(){
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a')
    var listLinks = new Array(links.length); 
    for(i = 0; i <links.length; i++){
        listLinks[i] = i; 
    }
    var mapLink = new Map([[listLinks, links]]) 
    return (mapLink)
}
var map = mapLinks();
```

now, what i want to do is to show the numbers (or the keys) on the web page, something like this:

[image: the link with the key associate to it]

I tried this code but it's not the best solution because in some case it distorts the structure of the web page

```js
function linksNumber(){ 
    for(var [key, value] of map){
        for(var i = 0, j = 0; i < key.length, j < value.length; i++, j++){
            value[j].textContent = value[j].textContent + key[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post the HTML you are working with so we can see how that would need to be done. Also, is there a reason why you need a separate array of the `a` elements? That's redundant since you are already putting them into a collection with `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: the reason why i separate array of the a is to make an association of keys/values...  keys are the numbers and values are the links. Also, my html code is really basic. there are only links. It's supposed to be a solution that should work on all web pages.

Comment: You really don't need an array to do that. `.querySelectorAll()` returns an array-like object that has indexes associated with each item in the collection.

Comment: Ok thanks, i didn't know that. Please, can you tell me how we can get the indexes of each item in the collection, if we use only .querySelectorAll() ?or maybe i have to post another task about that ?  I've searched a lot about that but i didn't found another solution than the map method.

Comment: Exactly the same way you do it with an array (`links[index]`). If you iterate the collection with `.forEach()`, the supplied callback function's second argument provides the index. Indexes in all arrays/collections start from zero.

Comment: See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the css `::before` or `::after` selector with `content: attr(data-n)` to keep the page structure basically the same.

```js
function mapLinks(){
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a')
    var listLinks = new Array(links.length); 
    for(i = 0; i <links.length; i++){
        links[i].setAttribute('data-n', i)
    }
    var mapLink = new Map([[listLinks, links]]) 
    return (mapLink)
}

mapLinks()
```

```css
a::after {
  content: attr(data-n);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<a href="test">Test</a>
<a href="hi">Hi</a>
```

If you can't add a css file, you can use JS to add an inline `<style`> element:

```
var sheet = document.createElement('style');
sheet.innerHTML = `
  a::after {
    content: attr(data-n);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: yellow;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: -6px;
  }
`
(document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]).appendChild(sheet);
```

Or, with no javascript except creating the stylesheet:

```js
var sheet = document.createElement('style');
sheet.innerHTML = `
      body { counter-reset: number -1; }
      a::after {
        content: counter(number);
        counter-increment: number;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        background: yellow;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 10px;
        position: relative;
        top: -6px;
      }
    `;
(document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]).appendChild(sheet);
```

```html
<a href="hello">Hello</a>
<a href="world">World</a>
```

Comment: thank you ! You made my day ...  this is exactly what i wanted to do.

Comment: Do u know if there is a another way to do the same without using a css file ? i mean, can we apply this style using only js ?

Comment: See edit, you just have to append a `<style>` element using js with the css you want

Answer (score 0):

The use of `.map()` is redundant here. `.querySelectorAll()` returns an array-like object which you can iterate using `.forEach()` and get the index from.

All you really need to do in the loop is just create a new element that will hold the "badge" value. Most of the work is actually in the CSS, not the JavaScript.

See inline comments:

```js
// Just loop over the collection returned by .querySelectorAll()
// with .forEach, which has a callback funciton that can provide
// you with the index.
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(link, index){
  let badge = document.createElement("span");
  badge.classList.add("badge");
  // Just use the index of the item you are iterating over
  badge.textContent = index + 1;
  link.appendChild(badge);
});
```

```css
/* Giving the new elements this class
   will allow them to "float" above the
   link element they correspond to. You 
   can tweak the top and left values for
   better positioning. */
.badge {
  position:absolute; /* puts in own layer */
  display:inline-block; /* let's us style as a block */
  border:1px solid #808080;
  padding:2px;
  background: #ff7;
  border-radius:3px;
  font-size:.7em;
  top:-.8em;  /* Moves the element relative to the parent <a> */
  left:-.8em; /* Moves the element relative to the parent <a> */
}

/* Basic styling for the links */
a {
  position:relative; /* doesn't move them, but puts them in their own layer */
  text-decoration:none; /* no underline */
  display:block;
  margin:1em;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  border:#e0e0e0;
  background-color:#99f;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#one">One</a>  
<a href="#two">Two</a>  
<a href="#three">Three</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Careful with this:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a')
```

If you have more `<a />` in the future, it will also take them. I recommend adding a class to the elements (`<a/>`) that you want to mark.

Lets say we add the class "anchorTooltip" to all  that you need.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a.anchorTooltip')
```

This will take all anchors with the class "anchorTooltip"

Now you can do:

```
Array.from(links).map((link, index)=>link.setAttribute("title", index))
```

`querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors. Use `Array.from()` to convert NodeList to array then iterate through `Array.map()`.

Tests:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a.anchorTooltip')

Array.from(links).map((link, index)=>link.setAttribute("title", index))
```

```html
  <a class="anchorTooltip">test 1</a><br >
  <a class="anchorTooltip">test 2</a><br >
  <a class="anchorTooltip">test 3</a>
```

### Without the Array.from():

```
document.querySelectorAll('a.anchorTooltip').forEach((link, index)=>link.setAttribute("title", index+40))
```

Test:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a.anchorTooltip').forEach((link, index)=>link.setAttribute("title", index+10))
```

```html
  <a class="anchorTooltip">test 1</a><br >
  <a class="anchorTooltip">test 2</a><br >
  <a class="anchorTooltip">test 3</a>
```

Comment: There is no need for an Array here. The node list from `.querySelector()` does the job.